# Java print on based position

Tags: java

Doing homework and I'm stuck.

Let's say I have an array colors:

```
["blue", "orange", "green", "black", "red" ]
```

and these colors occur in a text. When the color occurs there is another array that stores the line number in another array (position array).

[17,4,5,8,8]

Now I want to print by ascending line occurrence so the output would be:

```
orange
green
black
red
blue
```

I use the Arrays.sort() to sort the position array.
I believe that this should be done using position.

For example, for printing orange, there is a relation of the sorted array with the position of the color on the array colors.

Can you point me in some direction?

As I started to learn java this as to be done the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to associate the indices with each other. I would recommend you to do it in a class (maybe a `Pair` class with the attributes `String color` and `int line`).

   ```
   class Pair {
       public String color;
       public int line;
       public Pair(String color, int line) {
           this.color = color;
           this.line  = line;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Build up an array (or `List<Pair>`) of the paired objects.

   ```
   String[] colors = new String[] {"blue", "orange", "green", "black", "red"};
   int[] lines     = new int[]    {    17,        4,       5,       8,     8};

   List<Pair> pairs = new LinkedList<Pair>();
   for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
       pairs.add(new Pair(colors[i], lines[i]));
   ```
3. Sort the array of `Pair`s with an `Comparator` using `Arrays.sort` (or `Collection.sort`) method depending on your `line` attribute.

   ```
   Collections.sort(pairs, new Comparator<Pair>() {
       public int compare(Pair p1, Pair p2) {
           return Integer.valueOf(p2.line).compareTo(p1.line);
       }
   });
   ```

   Another option would be to implement `Comparable<Pair>` in `Pair`.
4. Print the array using a loop

Comment: Just started learning java now so this has to be done as simple as it gets. I know how to do step 4

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Comment: Just started learning java now so this has to be done as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and outputs:

> orange - 4
>   green - 5
>   black - 8
>   red - 8
>   blue - 17

Exmaple code:

```
public class Test
{  
    public String color;
    public int line;

    Test(String color, int line) {
        this.color = color;
        this.line = line;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] colors = new String[] { "blue", "orange", "green", "black", "red" };
        int[] lineNumber = new int[] { 17,4,5,8,8 };

        LinkedList<Test> out = new LinkedList<Test>();

        // add first element
        out.add(new Test(colors[0], lineNumber[0]));

        Loop: for(int i = 1; i < colors.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < out.size(); j++) {
                if(lineNumber[i] < out.get(j).line) {
                    out.add(j, new Test(colors[i], lineNumber[i]));
                    continue Loop;
                }
            }

            out.addLast(new Test(colors[i], lineNumber[i]));
        }

        for(Test t : out) {
            System.out.println(t.color + " - "+t.line);         
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap.
So for every color you have a Key by the color name
and for that Key you will need some sort of List of integers.

So what I would recommend is..

```
Map<String color, List<Integer> location> hashMap = new HashMap<String Color, List<Integer> location>();
```

if you want to add a position you do.

```
hashMap.get("orange").add(1);
```

which means you want to get the list of orange and add the value 1 to that list.

So if you want to iterate that list you would do..

```
List<Integer> location = hashMap.get("orange"); returning the whole orange list
```

and then

```
for(Integer int : location)
{
   //Do whatever
}
```

Comment: Just started learning java now so this has to be done as simple as it gets. Will edit first post to say that